# Sorting not working in mongoDB and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I have applied sorting on base of name of opportunity in descending order

```
db.SomeCollection.find().limit(10).sort({ "name" : -1 });
```

But its working fine with normal name like opprtunity one, singer and so on. Its not working if name like my's opportunity or Singer's data.

So basically its not working with special characters.

Anyone have experienced of this kind of problem. I appreciate for any help on this.

Comment: I once had an issue with sorting documents by field containing special characters. I ended up creating an alternative "formated" field with the same value without special chars, and sorting data on this alternative field.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get this kind of data you must use aggregate instead of find because Aggregate is giving a functionality to perform this type of complex query Like,

db.SomeCollection.aggregate([{$limit:5},{$sort:{"name": -1 }}]);

Comment: Is it possible without aggregate ?